# How to update the text based on the response value in quasar?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a q-table where I get a response from API. In one of the entries, it gives the value of the flag as 0 or 1 which I need to update it as Yes or No.
How can I do this?

I am using q-badge to change the bg color and highlight it but unable to update the text.

```
      <template v-slot:body-cell-processed="props">
        <q-td :props="props" >
          <q-badge style="background-color:white" :class="props.row.processed==0?'bg-red':'text-black'">
              {{ props.row.processed }}
            </q-badge>
        </q-td>
      </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tries this and it's working fine.

```
<q-td key="processed" :props="props">
            <q-badge style="background-color:white" :class="props.row.processed==0?'bg-red text-white text-weight-bolder':'bg-blue text-black'">
              {{ props.row.processed }}
            </q-badge>
          </q-td>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/PoqzzLx?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: That works. But my question was about updating the text to Yes or No based on the values.
If it is 1, I should set the text as No and otherwise.
Any inputs for this?

Comment: <span v-if="props.row.processed=='1'">Yes</span><span v-else>No</span> Try this